# Opened window too small from URL shortcut

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts, internet-explorer-8

I have a shortcut (url). When I double click on the shortcut, Internet Explorer opens the link in a really small window. Each time the window must be resized !

How is it possible to setup Internet Explorer to open the URL in a maximized window?

I already try the solution to delete the registry entry `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` but the new window is not maximized.

Comment: is it a website or a web based application? web based apps sometimes start in a windows of specific size..

Comment: In certain scenarios, you may have to resize (but not maximise) IE, close it, and then try again. Alternatively, I'd look at modifying the shortcut to open the window maximised.

Comment: as @RandolphWest said, you should be able to right-click on the shortcut and select the 'start maximized' option in there somewhere.

Comment: When clicking on the `Properties` there is no option for starting maximized.

Answer (score 1):

*lornix* is right.

In the properties window you will see **"Run"** option with a drop-down, by default its set to **"Normal Window"**. 
Change that to **"Maximized"**. 
This should solve the issue.

If it doesn't works then -You might be trying to Run a web application with pre-defined window dimensions.(as mentioned by *tumchaaditya*).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost too simple.

Open Windows explorer.
Select

Tools
Folder Options
File Types

Select Internet shortcut
Then
Advanced button
Edit button

Where it says "Application used to perform action" edit this line as follows

Add a space to the end of the text. Then Add    maximized

The result should look something like

"C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe" "C:\windows\system32\ieframe.dll",OpenURL %l maximized

Then press OK button and job is done.....Hopefully.

I tried this running XP and ie8 opens maximised every time